# Why doesn't this jQuery code to remove a border from a div work?

Tags: jquery, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWt53/)

I'm trying to remove the border of a div using jQuery, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: #f33; border: 10px solid silver;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a1"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="a3">click</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#a3").click(function() {
    $('#a1').css("border", ""); 
}):
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Element IDs cannot start with numbers
- Your scripts ends with `:`, not `;`
- Set `border` to `none`, not an empty string

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've updated the question. Still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you get the id's right, I think you want.

```
$("#three").click(function() {
    $('#one').css("border", "none"); 
});
```

If you set the border style to an empty string, it won't override that given by the CSS.  You need to give it a value that will be applied instead.  Using the empty string will remove the style property on the element, leaving the cascading style from the inline style tag to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got three problems:

1. Element IDs may not start with a number.
2. Your JS code ends with a `:` (colon); that should be a `;` (semicolon), or it's a syntax error.
3. Setting the border to an empty string doesn't remove the border. Try `$('#1').css('border', 'none');`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `css("border", "");` use `css("border", "none");`

But equally important is to change the `:` to `;` at the end of your script as it is causing it to fail completely.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/XWt53/4/

Answer (score 0):

Does the div you're clicking on have a click event bound to it?

```
$("#a3").bind('click', function () {
     $("#a1").css('border', 'none');
});
```